# CSS Grid or Columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns, css-grid

So I have already got my mobile version of my website laid out (see sketch below)

[image]

but now I am having trouble trying to achieve my envision goal for my desktop version. I did a quick sketch on paint to give you guys an idea of what I have so far.

[image]

The problem is though I want to keep my picture and textbox next to each other in the middle of the entire website. The paragraph and footer I can do myself. Is just I don't know what is the best solution to do to have my picture on the left side and the text on the right side while I can keep everything else on the bottom and do whatever I want there.

I want the picture (*left side*) and text (*right side*) to be like in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your picture and text in a div respectively and give that div below css

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 }
 .parent div{
 height:200px;
 width:300px;}
 
 .img img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="image">
<img src="https://cdn.colorlib.com/shapely/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2016/03/photo-1447834353189-91c48abf20e1-1-1.jpg"
          alt="">
</div>
<div class="text">
<h2>About Us</h2>
          <p>Usage of the Internet is becoming more common due to rapid advancement of technology and the power of
            globalization. Societies are becoming more inter-connected. Thoughts from different</p>
            <a href="">READ MORE</a>

</div>
</div>
```

}

Comment: Hey thanks! The only problem I had with your code that didn't fit to my liking was that I have to change some things around. So this part .img img{ width: 100%; height: 100%; } I had to delete the .img by removing the *period* img and leave it as img { and change the width and pixels to 170px instead of in percents. I even added in a padding in the .parent section to give it a nice place for my picture and text.