# Combination of CSS floats and divs + Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float, responsive-images

So I'm trying to get what I'm envisioning in my mind using a combination of **floats** and **divs** as well a **responsive image** for my background and text. *A few steps to take here.*

**1.** First one being this for example with image responsive https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_full_page.

**2.** Second one would be with text responsive https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_responsive_text.

**3.** And lastly, from the code below, I would like to take the **first div** to stack on top and the **second div** to stack on the bottom once it has resized into tablet/mobile size.

**3.1.** In tablet mode, the **first div** and the **second div** could stay in the center of the screen to give it a clean look, and then say once in iPhone size, the text h2 and paragraph could fill the screen from all the way on the left side to the right side of the screen.

**NOTE / FYI:**
 I plan to use the first div for an image.

Here is where I got the idea from this forum here that has received a lot of help.
[How to center two divs floating next to one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357310/how-to-center-two-divs-floating-next-to-one-another). I like the one that has the 6 upvote and then I tweaked it a little bit for myself and I got the following results that I liked. So take a look here. I'm more of a learn as I go kind of guy. So I'm still learning HTML and CSS and that I'm no pro. So a bonus would be if you could put comments after the semi-colon so that I know what each function does, that be great! Thanks!

**HTML**

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>This is a test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper" style="text-align:center;">

    <div style="float:left;background-color:red;width:50%">
      Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;background-color:blue;width:50%" ">
      Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet
    </div>
    
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First gold rule for such thing is to avoid float.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't exactly understand how the end result should look like. Could you attach some kind of an image? Also, most likely a flexbox is what you need instead of floats.

Comment: @TemaniAfif What do you propose I do to get what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: flexbox, CSS grid, inline-block .. and never float

Comment: @TemaniAfif So like this for example from one of my previous forums. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54320096/10332967 I like what he replied there. But it is not centered to how I picture it in this code that I just put.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I like it when it is in mobile but when it is in desktop. Kind of a bit off.

Comment: @MichałSadowski Is there a w3schools that have a topic on flexbox?

Comment: this should help you:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Azazel also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox a pretty comprehensive tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for!
I have become quite fond of using Flex for problems like this.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper
{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img
{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block; /*Gets Rid Of Spacing Under Images*/
}

#color1 {background: red;}
#color2 {background: blue;}

.box
{
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 750px){
  #wrapper
  {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="wrapper" style="text-align:center;">

    <div id="color1" class="box">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_girl.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="color2" class="box">
      Such A Beautiful Scene
    </div>
    
  </div>
```